# how to add multiple onChange in react for single input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange, state-management

I'm having a trouble of handling `state-management` and `event management` together on a single input element.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class profileDetail extends Component {
    continue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };

    back = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    };
    render() {
        const { values, handleChange } = this.props;

        const imageHandler = () => {

            //Do this thing..
            //make this magic happen...
        };
        return (
            <div>
                Add your Profile Picture:
                <input
-----HERE------>    onChange={handleChange('ProfilePic')}
      &             defaultValue={values.ProfilePic}
-----HERE------>    onChange={imageHandler}
                    type="file"
                    name="inpFile"
                    id="inpFile"
                    accept="image/*"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default profileDetail;
```

if i add two `onChange` on single input as above either i happen to get the state management working or either its the DOM manipulation with the onchange that gets working but not the both.

So, how and what changes should i make to get it working properly?

Comment: its because your attrs get converted into props, and the code behind this there is a javascript object, and you cant have two identical keys.  you need to defined a single event handler, that can call both actions you require.

Comment: You definitely don't need two click handlers, you may set your state changes inside `imageHandler` body

Answer (score 1):

Try using them both in the same function like `onChange`.

Also, note that the component's name should be Uppercased so it won't be treated as HTML element.

```
export class ProfileDetails extends Component {

  imageHandler = () => {
    /* ... */
  };

  onChange = () => {
    this.imageHandler();
    this.props.handleChange("ProfilePic");
  };

  render() {
    const { values } = this.props;

    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.onChange}
        defaultValue={values.ProfilePic}
        type="file"
        name="inpFile"
        id="inpFile"
        accept="image/*"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: by your method i manged to get the functionality working but the state management wasnt working at all. could you please check this detailed version of the current example [here](https://github.com/MeRahulAhire/cfm-dev-refined/blob/master/src/public/form/profileDetail.js) and suggest me on what should i do to get this working?

Comment: I don't know what "state management wasn't working at all" means without practical example, there are many mistakes in the link you shared, you should ask another question instead, due to: 1. It's out of the scope of current one. 2. Its too much information for a comment.

Comment: by state-management i mean the `handleChange` wasnt working correctly. i also have another [short example](https://codepen.io/rahulahire/pen/LYpQjma) exactly like it well under the scope of this question but it doesn't work exactly like what you suggested. can you please tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: im not sure why this was up voted, you shouldn't define functions in the render method - or they will get redefined each render.

Comment: @developer Good point, fixed. Also, the component name needs to be uppercased.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class profileDetail extends Component {
    continue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
        imageHandler = imageHandler.bind(this);
    };

    back = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    };
   const imageHandler = () => {

        //Do this thing..
        //make this magic happen...

        //and then call outer handler
        this.props.handleChange('ProfilePic');
    };
    render() {
        const { values } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                Add your Profile Picture:
                <input
                    defaultValue={values.ProfilePic}
                    onChange={imageHandler}
                    type="file"
                    name="inpFile"
                    id="inpFile"
                    accept="image/*"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you also would need to bind your imageHandler, so ive included: `imageHandler = imageHandler.bind(this);` in the constructor

Comment: hi @developer i managed to get the functionality working but not the state-management. can you please check this detailed [code](https://github.com/MeRahulAhire/cfm-dev-refined/blob/master/src/public/form/profileDetail.js) and suggest me what changes should i make?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a anonymous function to combine the two methods you want to call into one handler:

```js
<input
  onChange={() => {
    handleChange('ProfilePic');
    imageHandler();
  }}
  defaultValue={values.ProfilePic}
  type="file"
  name="inpFile"
  id="inpFile"
  accept="image/*"/>
```

Comment: by your method i manged to get the functionality working but the state management wasnt working at all. could you please check this detailed version of the current example [here](https://github.com/MeRahulAhire/cfm-dev-refined/blob/master/src/public/form/profileDetail.js) and suggest me on what should i do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function which could handle both the things for you `onChange`:

```
<input
  onChange={() => {
    handleChange('ProfilePic');
    imageHandler();
  }}
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: by your method i manged to get the functionality working but the state management wasnt working at all. could you please check this detailed version of the current example [here](https://github.com/MeRahulAhire/cfm-dev-refined/blob/master/src/public/form/profileDetail.js) and suggest me on what should i do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a commonHandleChange function that does both the actions, your code would look like below.

```
export class profileDetail extends Component {
   continue = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.props.nextStep();
   };

   back = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.prevStep();
   };

   const commonHandleChange = () => {
       // You can add conditions on which you want to execute both functions here, if you want to execute both function together.
       handleChange('ProfilePic');
       imageHandler();
   };
   render() {
      const { values } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
            Add your Profile Picture:
            <input
                defaultValue={values.ProfilePic}
                onChange={commmonHandleChange}
                type="file"
                name="inpFile"
                id="inpFile"
                accept="image/*"
            />
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```